# Quadrupedal Flight

Tags: flight

Ok, so, there is a character of mine that is a quadrupedal fox-rabbit-hybrid creature, and it has the magical power to sprout out wings of magical energy from their shoulders.
In order to make realistic flight scenes, I would like someone to tell me how would a quadrupedal creature with wings fly.
Their wings are shaped like that of an eagle.
The subject's height is 1 ft (30 cm) from the tip of their head to the ground and they weigh 14.3 lbs (6.5 kg). If you need to know more, let me know, and I'll try to provide you with more details.

The question is; how would they take off? Would they have to take a run in order to do so? And how would they land?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well its wings don't seem to be quite attached to it, and your magic wings here seem much more as a symbol that the magic is active rather than the means which it use to fly (though it does seem to circumvent in a way the problems of a hexapodal flyer regarding attachment points for the flight muscles and added weight issues).

But assuming it's wings actually impact on the way it flies (and disconsidering that the lack of tail feathers would make steering and balance tricky), whether it can take off vertically or will have to run while flapping its wings like swans and goose will depend a lot on its wing size and strength. Other than that, assuming your flying magic deals with the other issues, it'll fly pretty much like a normal bird, with a flapping pattern depending on its wings, and land like one.

Since in here we're not exactly worrying about muscle power and attachment points and your creature is in the right weight range, If your magical creature's wings are the same size and shape of a [Harpy eagle's](https://gringosabroad.com/harpy-eagle/), you should have no problems, as they can be even heavier than your creature. Harpy eagles are specially adapted to fly among the trees below the forest canopy, so it sounds like a good match for a creature that seems agile. As to how they fly and land, [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fS1TfANV0WA) should give you a good idea. With this wings, there's a good chance your creature could takeoff vertically with no need to run whatsoever (usually the birds who do run are heavier birds which don't have wings strong enough to allow for a take off, requiring them to gather momentum through running)

Comment: If the creature can sprout ethereal wings, why not ethereal tail feathers, too?

Comment: @John Dvorak good point.

Comment: Possibly the wizard didn't think of it until it was too late.

Comment: If the creature has a fox like tail, it should be able to maneuver well enough without tail feathers.  In fact, if it has a way to control  the alignment of the fur on its tail to shift between a vertical and horizontal rudder, it might even be able to pull off some maneuvers that proper birds cant even do.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - Reinstate Monica guess you're right, since flying squirrels already use their tails for controlling their direction when gliding, though,I still think feathers would be necessary to aid in stabilizing the lower body and thus granting a more controlled flight.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Your answer was very helpful

Comment: @ProjectApex how fast could they go?

Comment: @DuskForm going by the harpy eagle as a reference, I'd say around 80 km/h or 49,7 mph. Not the absolute fastest but not too slow for a medieval setting.

Comment: @ProjectApex what set of wings could I give them to make them faster?

Comment: @DuskForm how faster? The fastest flying animal regarding wing flapping (and not diving speed) is the Brazilian short tailed bat, at 160 km/h. Twice the speed of a harpy eagle. These bats usually weight 20 grams at max and don't grow larger than 6 cm. A peregrine falcon can dive at much faster speeds, but it's not as fast regarding normal flight, usually flying at 60 km/h

Comment: @ProjectApex one thing: how much weight could they carry?

Comment: @DuskForm harpy eagles can carry up to 20 pounds/ around 9 kg. Your creature could probably have a similar carrying capacity.